# pecl install xdebug not recognized the os php version on mac

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug, pecl, php-7.1

im trying to install xdebug on my mac(mojave) for debug phpunit on phpstorm.
i success running phpunit but unable to run debug.
Im using xampp with php 5.5 and my os have php 7.1 installed

> php -v

PHP 7.1.19 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2018 18:03:17) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

When i run:

> pecl install xdebug

i get :
pecl/xdebug requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.5.38
No valid packages found
install failed

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What macOS do you have? Do you use PHP from macOS? Do you use Brew?

Comment: MacOS mojave 
When I run php -v command I get php 7.1
How can brew help here ?

Comment: Do you have anywhere php 5.5.38 installed?

Comment: yes, php 5.5 installed on xampp